# Getting the r-squared value using curve_fit

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am a beginner with both Python and all its libs. But I have managed to make a small program that works as intended. 
It takes a string, counts the occurence of the different letters and plots them in a graph and then applies a equation and its curve.¨
Now i would like to get the r-squared value of the fit.

The overall idea is to compare different kinds of text from articles on different levels and see how strong the overall pattern is.

Is just an excersise and I am new, so a easy to understand answer would be awesome.

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import figure, show
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

s="""det, og deres undersøgelse af hvor meget det bliver brugt viser, at der kun er seks plugins, som benyttes af mere end 5 % af Chrome-brugere.
Problemet med teknologien er, at den ivivuilv rduyd iytf ouyf ouy yg oyuf yd iyt erzypu zhrpyh dfgopaehr poargi ah pargoh ertao gehorg aeophgrpaoghraprbpaenbtibaeriber en af hovedårsagerne til sikkerhedshuller, ustabilitet og deciderede nedbrud af browseren.
Der vil ikke bve lukket for API'et  ivivuilv rduyd iytf ouyf ouy yg oyuf yd iyt erzypu zhrpyh dfgopaehr poargi ah pargoh ertao gehorg aeophgrpaoghraprbpaenbtibaeriber en af hovedårsagerne til sikkerhedshuller, ustabilitet og deciderede nedbrud af browseren.
Der vil ikke blive lukket for API'et på én gang, men det vil blive udfaset i løbet af et års tid. De mest populære plugins får lov at fungere i udfasningsperioden; Det drejer sig om: Silverlight (anvendt af 15 % af Chrome-brugere sidste måned), Unity (9,1 %), Google Earth (9,1 %), Java (8,9%), Google Talk (8,7 %) og Facebook Video (6,0 %).
Det er muligt at hvidliste andre plugins, men i slutningen af 2014 forventer udviklerne helt at lukke for brugen af dem."""
fordel=[]
alf=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','æ','ø','å']
i=1
p=0
fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,0)
for i in range(len(alf)):
    fordel.append(s.count(alf[i]))
    i=i+1   
fordel=sorted(fordel,key=int,reverse=True)
yFit=fordel
xFit=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
def func(x, a, b):
    return a * (b ** x)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xFit, yFit)
t = np.arange(0.0, 30.0, 0.1)
a=popt[0]
b=popt[1]
s = (a*b**t)
ax1.plot(t,s)
print(popt)
yMax=math.ceil(fordel[0]+5)
ax1.axis([0,30,0,yMax])
for i in range(0,int(len(alf))*2,2):
    fordel.insert(i,p)
    p=p+1
for i in range(0,int(len(fordel)/2)):
    ax1.scatter(fordel[0],fordel[1])
    fordel.pop(0)
    fordel.pop(0)
plt.show()
show()
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Computing [image: r_squared]:**

The [image: r_squared] value can be found using the *mean* ([image: mean]), the *total sum of squares* ([image: ss_tot]), and the *residual sum of squares* ([image: ss_res]). Each is defined as:

[image: mean]

[image: SStot]

[image: SSres]

[image: rsquared]

where [image: f_i] is the function value at point [image: x_i]. Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination).

**From `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()`:**

- You can get the parameters (`popt`) from `curve_fit()` with

  `popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata)`
- You can get the *residual sum of squares* ([image: ss_tot]) with

  - `residuals = ydata- f(xdata, *popt)`
  - `ss_res = numpy.sum(residuals**2)`
- You can get the *total sum of squares* ([image: ss_tot]) with

  `ss_tot = numpy.sum((ydata-numpy.mean(ydata))**2)`
- And finally, the [image: r_squared]-value with,

  `r_squared = 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)`

Comment: OFC! Brilliant answer. For some reason I didn't consider just calculating it myself though it seems rather straight forward. Thanks.

Comment: two questions: 1. shouldn't popt be replaced with *popt in residual equation? 2. why not using pcov?

Comment: this is equally useful like answering: "take pen and pencil, open Wikipedia and code it yourself man!". For linear fits in `scipy` we have it as standard output, for any solvers this outputs in a form of neat table full of t-stats, p-values, log-likelihoods etc. And suddenly for 'curve_fit' the best answer is: "code it yourself".....

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be some [background](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8439) about R<sup>2</sup> not being implemented directly in `scipy`.

You can use [sklearn.metrics.r2_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html).

From your example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xFit, yFit)
y_pred = func(xFit, *popt)
r2_score(yFit, y_pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is an easier way to solve the minimize problem:

```
res = minimize(func)  # your optimize function
cof = np.reshape(np.array(res.x),(-1,1))
r_square = 1.0 - (np.var(ydata-xdata.dot(cof)) / np.var(ydata))

# or 
# r_square = 1 - np.square(ydata-xdata.dot(cof)).sum() / (np.var(ydata) * len(ydata))
```