# Getting a negative R-squared value with curve_fit()

Tags: python, statistics, regression, non-linear-regression, scikit-optimize

I've read a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189362/getting-the-r-squared-value-using-curve-fit) on manually calculating R-squared values after using scipy.optimize.curve_fit(). However, they calculate an R-squared value when their function follows the power-law (f(x) = a*x^b). I'm trying to do the same but get negative R-squared values.

Here is my code:

```
def powerlaw(x, a, b):
    '''Generic power law function.'''
    return a * x**b
X = s_lt[4:] # independent variable (Pandas series)
Y = s_lm[4:] # dependent variable (Pandas series)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(powerlaw, X, Y)
residuals = Y - powerlaw(X, *popt)
ss_res = np.sum(residuals**2)   # residual sum of squares
ss_tot = np.sum((Y-np.mean(Y))**2)  # total sum of squares
r_squared = 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)   # r-squared value
print("R-squared of power-law fit = ", str(r_squared))
```

I got an R-squared value of -0.057....

From my understanding, it's not good to use R-squared values for non-linear functions, but I expected to get a much higher R-squared value than a linear model due to overfitting. Did something else go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See [The R-squared and nonlinear regression: a difficult marriage?](https://www.statforbiology.com/2021/stat_nls_r2/).  Also [When is R squared negative?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/when-is-r-squared-negative).

> Basically, we have two problems:
>
> 1. nonlinear models do not have an intercept term, at least, not in the usual sense;
> 2. the equality SStot=SSreg+SSres may not hold.

The first reference above denotes your statistic "pseudo-R-square" (in the case of non-linear models), and notes that it **may be lower than 0**.

To further understand what's going on you probably want to plot your data Y as a function of X, the predicted values from the power law as a function of X, and the residuals as a function of X.

For non-linear models I have sometimes calculated the sum of squared deviation from zero, to examine how much of that is explained by the model.  Something like this:

```
pred = powerlaw(X, *popt)
ss_total = np.sum(Y**2)  # Not deviation from mean.
ss_resid = np.sum((Y - pred)**2)
pseudo_r_squared = 1 - ss_resid/ss_total
```

Calculated this way, `pseudo_r_squared` can potentially be negative (if the model is really bad, worse than just guessing the data are all 0), but if `pseudo_r_squared` is positive I interpret it as the amount of "variation from 0" explained by the model.