# How to get r-squared using the covariance matrix output of scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

Tags: python, covariance-matrix

The scipy.optimize.curve_fit outputs covariance matrix, see [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit). I wish to get a single float description of the fitting result and I was use to compare r-squared, the coefficient of determination.

How to get r-squared using the covariance matrix output of scipy.optimize.curve_fit?

I would calculate the r-squared from the dataset https://medium.com/swlh/covariance-correlation-r-sqaured-5cbefc5cbe1c#1ae3 otherwise.

Comment: Or in other words: What single (float) characteristic value/parameter can I draw from the fitting results?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the r-squared value using curve\_fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189362/getting-the-r-squared-value-using-curve-fit)